# Why does labeling outer alternatives in an ANTLR4 rule prevent this rule from being available in a visitor/listener?

Tags: java, antlr4

For a rule like the following:

```
lastFormalParameter
        :       variableModifier* unannType annotation* ELLIPSIS variableDeclaratorId #LastParamVarargs
        |       formalParameter #LastParamBasic
        ;
```

where alternatives are labeled (`#`), why won't the generated visitors/listeners include `visitLastFormalParameter`/`enterLastFormalParameter`/`exitLastFormalParameter` methods for user code to override? Only the methods for the outer alternative labels may be overridden. Is there a way to make the tool generate the missing methods in a way other than replacing the labeled alternatives with actual rules (below)?

```
lastFormalParameter
        :       lastParamVarargs
        |       lastParamBasic
        ;
lastParamVarargs
        :       variableModifier* unannType annotation* ELLIPSIS variableDeclaratorId
        ;
lastParamBasic
        :       formalParameter 
        ;
```

This is with 4.7.

Answer (score 0):

I explained that 2 days ago in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44531576/why-does-antlr-require-all-or-none-alternatives-be-labeled?answertab=votes#tab-top). The main point with labels here is that the rule context is replaced with individual contexts for each alt.

Comment: At least to me, this seems like a bug. It should be configurable. In my case when I'm parsing code that is only partially valid, the parent context will be recognized (and for example shown in the parse tree visualization), but not the alternatives - this means their callbacks will never be hit in listener/visitor, yet the parent's rule would be, but it cannot be accessed. Incredibly frustrating, since the parser did recognize exactly what you wanted, but it just teases you with it, almost taunting you.

Comment: Regardless of whether the rule alts are labeled, if none are matched by the parser, then no rule node will be added to the parse-tree. There will simply be no rule or labeled alt context to visit. Even in the exploded rule example, if neither `lastParamVarargs` nor `lastParamBasic` rules are matched, then the `lastFormalParameter` rule will not be matched. The parser will therefore not generate a `LastFormalParameterContext` node in the parse tree -- a visitor will have nothing to visit.

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44531664/878469) and @MikeLischke's link, this is normal.

You can still visit or listen for the rule that is removed by implementing a generic callback and delegating to a "fake" one, if you need to implement functionality common to all alternatives.

For example, in a visitor, you would override `visit(ParseTree)`, which gets called for every rule, and then check if it represents the target parent rule. It is still a part of the parse tree, but as a superclass to the rule that is actually hit (one of the labeled alternatives).

```java
@Override
public Object visit(ParseTree tree) {
    if (tree instanceof LastFormalParameterContext) {
        return visitLastFormalParameterContext((LastFormalParameterContext) tree);
    }
    return super.visit(tree);
}

private Object visitLastFormalParameterContext(LastFormalParameterContext ctx) {
    // ...
    return null;
}
```

In a listener, you have `enterEveryRule(ParserRuleContext)` and `exitEveryRule(ParserRuleContext)` at your disposal to achieve the same.